# Tools to check grammar when programming

Tags: php, grammar

I am programming in PHP and I want to check if there are any mistakes in my website and if there are, it would highlight those words which are written incorrect. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: You could write your content in a word processor first. IDEs aren't really designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Define "mistake" in your website. Are you thinking about spelling/grammar mistakes?

Comment: It can be browser add-on or smth, not necessarily in IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Publish your website.
2. Visit it in your browser.
3. Copy/paste the contents into MS Word.
4. Run spelling & grammar check.

Comment: Copy/Paste and running spelling/grammar check in MS-word is hard to automate.

Comment: @Noufal: Yes, but how often do you write large blocks of copy? Usually you write this once. It's the programming stuff that gets developed iteratively. And if your logic is entwined with your presented prose, you've done it wrong.

Comment: Yes but I'd like the grammar and spelling testing to be part of my release cycle and CI system. Not something I have to do manually. For example, I have written "unit tests" for my docs to see if they all confirm to a certain "pattern" (intro, description, examples etc.) and spelling checks. Developers are required to pass these tests before they can check the doc sources in and the CI system runs these tests to make sure that there are no mistakes.

Comment: @Noufal: Fair enough. I'd usually separate code testing from content proofing, but I can understand why you might want _both_ automated if you have a big system with frequently-changing content.

Comment: I would separate them if they were being handled by different teams (e.g a team of writers doing the copy while a team of coders did the programming). In our setup, the engineers were required to write the docs and being a bit of a grammar and spelling Nazi myself, I instituted this to keep the docs somewhat sane.

Answer (score 2):

Many editors provide a selective kind of spell checking which ignores program constructs and spell checks only comments and parts like that. Emacs for example comes with `flyspell-prog-mode` which will restrict on the fly spell checking to the code comments.

The other possibility is to run the `php` command line interpreter on your source files and pipe that through `aspell -a` to give you a summary of spelling mistakes. This is on Linux.

As for grammar, I'm not aware of any command line tools that can do it so cutting/pasting seems to be the only way to go.